# Sidekiq worker not working from Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a rails app using an engine where Sidekiq workers are defined. The worker's `perform_async` is invoked in a controller within the engine. The worker's `perform` does the work on arguments passed in through that controller. The worker specific queue is defined in the worker class too. However, when a request comes in to that controller, it gets pushed to the redis server from 'perform_async', to the right queue. A `bundle exec sidekiq` starts up Sidekiq. However, the worker's `perform` never gets executed. Checking the sidekiq UI, I can see that the job is in the right queue. 
This is how my worker looks like

```
require 'pando'

class PandoWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options :queue => :pando, :backtrace=> true

  def perform(*args)
    puts "in here"
    puts args
  end

end
```

So in this case the sidekiq UI shows that the args are queued in 'pando'. The sidekiq process never processes from that queue or even the default.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell sidekiq process which queue to look at:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q pando
```

Otherwise process is only watching 'default' queue.

Comment: Does using the sidekiq.yml work with the queues defined in them? And how to use those in an engine?

Comment: Accoridng to docs sidekiq.yml sould do the trick as well: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options